# kotlin: debugging a run of same function with 2 set of parameters command by command

Tags: kotlin, debugging, intellij-idea, parallel-processing, functional-programming

I'm looking for a good way to compare the run of a (pure) function with 2 sets of arguments in parallel.

for instance

```
fun test1(i: Int) : Int {
    var res = i*2
    res /= 3
    return res+1
}
```

I want to debug:

```
test1(1)
test1(0)
```

and see the debugger line by line for both runs.

expected is:

```
line1: thread1: res=1 vs thread2: res=0
line2: thread2: res=2 vs thread2: res=0
```

etc...

I could change test1 but imagine that I have complex input and complex function...

Comment: Just fire up two instances of the debugger and two instances of your program?

Comment: yeah, it might do the work with 'Allow multiple instances'

Comment: @Sweeper it would be nice also if I can split the 2 tabs of debug window to side by side. do you know a way